# Python as a Windows Watchdog

Tags: python, winapi

Hi I'm considering using Python to make a watchdog app on Windows XP that will perform the following actions:

- Restart Windows at a given time.
- Start an exe application.
- Run a timer to check: is an application still running

I know of the existence of PyWin32, but I hear that the API is not complete. So my question is can Python perform these actions on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want this to work on Windows, the easiest way to do that is to use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) and make system-specific calls from within a Python program.

Use the built in Windows tool to run programs at a particular time.

Use shutdown -r to reboot Windows.

Use tasklist to list all processes, then search that list. If you need to manipulate a process as well, the best way I know of is the COM method described [here](http://74.125.113.132/search?q=cache:8BxqRjSz9kYJ:mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-May/035338.html+windows+find+process&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).